# Provide a second generic type conditionally based on the first type

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I'm trying to generate a class definition for `mongoose` where I would like to use the first generic to select the second generic. A simplified concept version would look something like this:

```
class StringClass {
    val: string;

    constructor(val: string) {
        this.val = val;
    }
}

class NumberClass {
    val: number;

    constructor(val: number) {
        this.val = val;
    }
}

class test<A extends string | number, B extends typeof StringClass | typeof NumberClass) {
    val: B;
    
    constructor(val: A, Class: B) {
        this.val = new Class(val);
    }
}
```

I would like to change the test to be defined as:

```
class test<A extends string | number, B extends (A instanceof string ? typeof StringClass : typeof NumberClass)) {
    val: B;
    
    constructor(val: A, Class: B) {
        this.val = new Class(val);
    }
}
```

This is not valid in Typescript 4.4 and thus I wonder, how do I make the second generic dependent on the first parameter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Why this error appears ?**
Here you have an example:

```js
class StringClass {
    val: string;

    constructor(val: string) {
        this.val = val;
    }
}

class NumberClass {
    val: number

    constructor(val: number) {
        this.val = val;
    }
}

type Check<A> = A extends string ? typeof StringClass : typeof NumberClass

class test<A extends string | number, B extends Check<A>> {
    val: B;
    constructor(val: A, Class: B) {
        // Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'never'
        this.val = new Class(val);
    }
}

const result = new test('2', StringClass)
```

In above case `val` infered to `never`, because

> multiple candidates for the same type variable in contra-variant positions causes an intersection type to be inferred.

Hence `string & number === never`

COnsider this example:

```js
class StringClass {
    val: { string: string };

    constructor(val: { string: string }) {
        this.val = val;
    }
}

class NumberClass {
    val: { number: number }

    constructor(val: { number: number }) {
        this.val = val;
    }
}

type Check<A> = A extends string ? typeof StringClass : typeof NumberClass

class test<A extends string|number, B extends Check<A>> {
    val: B;
    constructor(val: A, Class: B) {
        // Type 'string' is not assignable to type '{ string: string; } & { number: number; }'
        this.val = new Class(val);
    }
}

const result = new test('2', StringClass)
```

`val` is `{ string: string; } & { number: number; }`.

**So, how to fix it?**

You can get rid of generics and overload your constructor with appropriate restrictions

```js
class StringClass {
    val: string;

    constructor(val: string) {
        this.val = val;
    }
}

class NumberClass {
    val: number

    constructor(val: number) {
        this.val = val;
    }
}

type Check<A> = A extends string ? typeof StringClass : typeof NumberClass

interface Overloading {
    new(val: string): any
    new(val: number): any
    new(val: string | number): any
}

class test {
    val: StringClass | NumberClass
    constructor(val: number, Class: typeof NumberClass)
    constructor(val: string, Class: typeof StringClass)
    constructor(val: never, Class: typeof StringClass & typeof NumberClass) {
        this.val = new Class(val)

    }
}

const _ = new test('2', StringClass) // ok
const __ = new test(2, StringClass) // expected error
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/LAKFGMBsEMGdYAQGUAuAnAlgOwOYGEZ4EBvUBchAN2kgC4FZ1scBuUMi8Aey0bQFdwKLmgAU1Ogya4AlCQ4UKKABYZYAOgkIAvFRpsQigL6gTYEFDiIAcvwC2AIwCmaAlfmGKE%20lnvO07J7k3LzogsJi3gi%20ji5ypEGKCCpqmjQ6epAGxqaBlkQoToweilGomLhuRAA%20CLaxroSwCgghfOEi4jQ%20fi4ANAhVsPQoAJ4ADk5cAGZ1vY1WMi1tYUKdUXzMA0MjE1Oz5cxDS4krAmuR3dFOlP2DTbuTM8jS%20E0IAGTJe8-1-sclJLkFIaLS6LBOADu9ysXUgJxaZjMEB4xQA%20hkIdDCoxRAByABMeIGh0qTTkAHoKQguABrFGhBBojHgqHJIooUQEkmvAFUhBOAAekyETgAJgK0GgRIFZeYgA)

In general, runtime values can't rely on generic conditions (see `Check`). It is not safe.

This is why here:

```js
class StringClass {
    val: string;

    constructor(val: string) {
        this.val = val;
    }
}

class NumberClass {
    val: number

    constructor(val: number) {
        this.val = val;
    }
}

class test<A, B extends {
    0: typeof StringClass,
    1: typeof NumberClass,
    2: never
}[A extends string ? 0 : A extends number ? 1 : 2]> {
    val: B
    constructor(val: A, Class: B) {
        this.val = new Class(val) // error

    }
}
```

you have an error.

YOu can always use type assertion `as never` in this case:

```js
class StringClass {
    val: string;

    constructor(val: string) {
        this.val = val;
    }
}

class NumberClass {
    val: number

    constructor(val: number) {
        this.val = val;
    }
}

class test<A, B extends {
    0: typeof StringClass,
    1: typeof NumberClass,
    2: never
}[A extends string ? 0 : A extends number ? 1 : 2]> {
    val: StringClass | NumberClass
    constructor(val: A, Class: B) {
        this.val = new Class(val as never) // type asserion

    }
}

const _ = new test('2', StringClass) // ok
const __ = new test(2, StringClass) // expected error
```

Is it safe to use type assertion here? I'm not sure. I think it is up to you. If this code is just for testing - use `as never` or `never` just like I did.

If this a production code - please use conditional statements

Comment: Awesome answer! As I mentioned in the beginning the real example involves mongoose where I have two different model-types depending on the base type - one is a regular model while the other is a plugin-extended model. I guess the last example solves the issue but it feels like voodoo and probably not really recommended...

Comment: @MaxGordon you are right, I can't personally recommend this way. Like I said, PROD code should be with `conditional statements`